# Finding upper and lower bounds for triple integral $ \iiint_J x \,dV. $

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

Let  $D$  be the subset of  $R^3$  given by $ x\ge 1$ ,  $y\ge 4$ and  $xy\le z\le 12$.

Need to compute $ \iiint_J x \,dV$.

First I need to find the bounds where $ \int_{l_1}^{u_1} \int_{l_2}^{u_2} \int_{l_3}^{u_3} x\,dz\,dy\,dx. $ So the order is $dzdydx$

I'm struggling to find the bounds. So far I have some thoughts:

since $x\ge 1$ and  $y\ge 4$, $xy\ge 4$, so $4\le z\le 12 $.

And $x\ge 1$ and since it is less than $12\ge z$, $1\le x\le 12$.

And $y\ge 4$ and since it is less than $12\ge z$, $4\le y\le 12$.

I'm not sure if this is right and how I should approach solving for the bounds. I'm trying to do it without drawing a graph, but if making one helps then I'm open to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start with the interior-most integration, and ask, what are the bounds placed on $z$ by the domain: $\{(x,y,z)\in\Bbb R^3: 1\leq x~, 4\leq y~, xy\leq z\leq 12\}$?

We simply bound $z$ by $xy\leq z\leq 12$.

The logical next step is: to move outwards, having "integrated out" $z$.

Thus for the middle integration, we need $y$ to satisfy $4\leq y$ *and* $xy\leq 12$.

Thus we bound $y$ by $4\leq y\leq 12/x$ .

Likewise, the outermost integration must be bounded by $1\leq x$ *and* $4\leq 12/x$.

That is bound $x$ by $1\leq x\leq 3$.

$$\int_1^3\int_4^{12/x}\int_{xy}^{12} x\,\mathrm d z\,\mathrm d y\,\mathrm dx $$

Comment: Thanks so much, your explanation really helped! It makes so much more sense now. I have troubles drawing out graphs and interpreting them, so doing it with the inequalities this way helps out a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You should sketch the region.

Intersection of plane $z = 12 ~ $ with surface $ ~ z = xy ~ $ is curve $ ~ xy = 12$.

At $x = 1, y = 12$ and at $y = 4, x = 3$. Now note that for any $x$ and $y$ in $1 \leq x \leq 3, 4 \leq y \leq 12$, $xy \leq z \leq 12$. So it is easier to set up the innermost integral with respect to $dz$ first.

Next integral can be either with respect to $dx$ or $dy$ with lower bound as $x = 1$ or $y = 4$ and upper bound being on the curve $xy = 12$.

That leads to the integral,

$ \displaystyle  \int_1^3 \int_4^{12/x} \int_{xy}^{12} x ~ dz ~ dy ~ dx$

OR

$ \displaystyle  \int_4^{12} \int_1^{12/y} \int_{xy}^{12} x ~ dz ~ dx ~ dy$

---

Also, here is one of the orders of integral with $dz$ as the outermost integral.

$ \displaystyle  \int_4^{12} \int_4^{z} \int_{1}^{z/y} x ~ dz ~ dy ~ dx$

You can work out other orders for learning purpose.

Comment: How do you sketch the region? I'm having troubles drawing it out in 3D. I made a line (represent the plane) for z=12 and drew a parabola like shape for the xy curve, but I can't figure out how to interpret the graph, especially without using an online graphing calculator.

Comment: @Eugene there are two ways to go about it. I usually sketch $2D$ projections of it in different planes and that makes the visualization a bit easier. Alternatively during practice and learning process, you can take help from an online tool like https://www.geogebra.org/3d

Comment: how do you sketch the 2D projections?

Comment: If we are going with $dz$ first, think first of the projection in plane $z = 12$. You can see bounds being $x = 1, y = 4$ and $xy = 12$. Similarly think of projections in plane $x = 1$ and $y = 4$.

Comment: A lot of  these $3D$ volume integrals are solved by looking for a coordinate plane or a plane parallel to a coordinate plane where the region can be projected. Then we first look at bounds to find area of the projected region and then for each point what is the bounds of third coordinates.

Comment: For example in this case when you sketch the region in plane $z = 12$, you see the bounds to find area is $1 \leq x \leq 12/y, 4 \leq y \leq 12$ or $4 \leq y \leq 12/x, 1 \leq x \leq 3$. Then we check whether for every point we have a single bound of $z$ or do we have to split? In this case we see the bound of $z$ is simply $xy \leq z \leq 12$